# How to create multiple lists of data that can be looked through for specific specifications

Tags: python, string, list, text-files

```
sf = input('pick a number between 1-5: ')
string = ''
with open('dna.txt','r')as f:
    count = 0
    for line in f:
        row = list(map(str, line.strip().split()))
        Letter, number = row
        n=int(number)
        chunks = [row[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(row),2)]
        for x in chunks:
            print(x)
            if x >= sf:
                string += x
```

After getting a user input, it needs to search through the created lists for values equal to or greater than the given value and be added to 'string'. in the text file the first column are all letters and the second are all numbers. Is it possible to have the number column become an int?

[This is what the data looks like]
                [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM3aJ.png

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Could you paste the text of the sample data instead of linking a screenshot of it?

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Also provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: Your code is confusing, both in poor variable names and in logic.  For instance, you unpack exactly two items from each row, but later iterate through the same row in steps of 2.  You ask whether the second column can be an `int`, but you're already making it an `int` explicitly.

Comment: Off-site links and images of critical code and data are not acceptable.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind next time, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the second column to be an int, you don't want to be returning the data as a single string; a list of `(str, int)` tuples would allow you to keep track of both values with their correct types.

I think this is closer to what you're aiming for:

```
from typing import List, Tuple


def read_values_with_minimum(
    path: str,
    n: int
) -> List[Tuple[str, int]]:
    with open(path) as f:
        return [
            (s, int(v))
            for s, v in (
                line.strip().split()
                for line in f.readlines()
            )
            if int(v) >= n
        ]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sf = int(input('pick a number between 1-5: '))
    assert 1 <= sf <= 5
    print("\n".join(
        map(str, read_values_with_minimum("dna.txt", sf))
    ))
```